Nesting PdfDiv in iText 5
I'm trying to simulate the following HTML with iText 5:
<blockquote>
  In the outer blockquote
    <blockquote>
      In the inner blockquote
    </blockquote>
  Back to the outer blockquote
</blockquote>

blockquote{margin-left: 2.5em;}

To simulate the margins I put the strings in PdfDiv and set the padding. So I have this code:
   Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
   paragraph1.add("In Paragraph1 #1");
    
      PdfDiv div1 = new PdfDiv(); 
      div1.setPaddingLeft(50.0f);
      paragraph1.add(div1);
    
        Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph();
        paragraph2.add("In Paragraph2 #1");
        div1.addElement(paragraph2);
        
          PdfDiv div2 = new PdfDiv(); 
          div2.setPaddingLeft(50.0f);
          paragraph2.add(div2);
      
            Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph();
            paragraph3.add("In Paragraph3 #1");
            div2.addElement(paragraph2);
        
        paragraph2.add("In Paragraph2 #2");
    
    paragraph1.add("In Paragraph1 #2");

(sorry for the non-standard formatting, I found it easier to read and follow this way)
When I run this code I don't get the strings for Paragraph3 printed out. I believe that it has to do with putting a PdfDiv  inside of another PdfDiv.
If there a limitation on using nested PdfDivs? If so, what should I use to create nested margins?
